# sparknlp.annotator Doc2VecApproach: obtain vocabulary

Tags: pyspark

The documentation of `Doc2VecApproach` contains this sentence:

*The algorithm first constructs a vocabulary from the corpus and then learns vector representation of words in the vocabulary. The vector representation can be used as features in natural language processing and machine learning algorithms.*

I would like to retrieve the vocabulary of the `Doc2VecApproach` object. Is this possible?

Example below:

```
import sparknlp

from sparknlp.base import *

from sparknlp.annotator import *

from pyspark.ml import Pipeline

documentAssembler = DocumentAssembler() \

    .setInputCol("text") \

    .setOutputCol("document")

tokenizer = Tokenizer() \

    .setInputCols(["document"]) \

    .setOutputCol("token")

embeddings = Doc2VecApproach() \

    .setInputCols(["token"]) \

    .setOutputCol("embeddings")

pipeline = Pipeline() \

    .setStages([

      documentAssembler,

      tokenizer,

      embeddings

    ])

path = "sherlockholmes.txt"

dataset = spark.read.text(path).toDF("text")

pipelineModel = pipeline.fit(dataset)
```